# ¿Existe un log de transacciones en Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Necesito hacer un log de transacciones para el CRUD del sistema. Sé que se puede hacer mediante triggers que dispare la acción de guardar el registro en una tabla de transacciones pero ¿Laravel tiene esta funcionalidad?

Comment: Mira la documentación para capturar todas las consultas que se lanzan a la base de datos: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#listening-for-query-events

Answer (score 1):

Sí, a través del método *transaction*. Ejemplo:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    DB::table('mensajes')->delete();
});
```

Un saludo